# How to get XStream to map old deleted field to a new one of a different type?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

We've made changes to our objectmodel and hence XML, such that some boolean fields are no longer used and superseded by enums.

For example say the object had

```
@XStreamAlias("showABC")
private boolean showABC;
```

and that's now superseded by

```
@XStreamAlias("showOption")
private ShowOptions showOption;
```

I'd like to **remove** the defunct booleans **but** need to be able to read old XML that still contains them as the new field needs to be initialised base on the value of the old..

Currently we just leave the old fields behind and mark them `@Deprecated` so they can still be read and have `readResolve()` do the initialisation e.g.

```
if (showABC == false) {
    showOption = ShowOptions.NONE;
}
```

Leaving these fields around is ugly as hell though, polluting the XML!

**Is there a way to delete the fields and create a converter to do the right thing?** I don't want to create a converter that manually reads all the fields as there's LOTS of them.

Currently leaning towards another ugly approach of extending `AbstractReflectionConverter` and munging about in `doUnmarshal()` so I can have `handleUnknownField()` do something more useful..

But is there a better solution? Perhaps through the use of `Mappers` although I can't find any details in the docs/tuts, just right to the source.

**UPDATE**

Whilst looking at the use of `Mapper`s in `AbstractReflectionConverter` I thought I might get lucky by making the old field an alias of the new and having a converter that can deal with the boolean and the enum:

```
xstream.aliasField("showABC", MyModel.class, "showOption");
xstream.registerLocalConverter(MyModel.class, "ShowOptions", new ShowConverter());
```

But wouldn't you know, this throws a `DuplicateFieldException` so this approach would need munging to allow overwriting (as of course we've got intermediate XML with both the old and new in it o_O); fortunately new fields are declared after the old so ordering is ok..

I'd have thought this kind of conversion requirement isn't uncommon?!